# Overriding method with selector init has incompatible type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift, and I am trying to subclassing like below:

```
public class CombinedChartRenderer: ChartDataRendererBase {

    private weak var _chart: CombinedChartView!

    public init(chart: CombinedChartView, animator: ChartAnimator, viewPortHandler: ChartViewPortHandler)
    {
        super.init(animator: animator, viewPortHandler: viewPortHandler)

        _chart = chart

        createRenderers()
    }
}

public class MyCombinedChartRenderer: CombinedChartRenderer {
    private weak var _chart: MyCombinedChartView!
    public override init(chart: MyCombinedChartView, animator: ChartAnimator, viewPortHandler: ChartViewPortHandler)
    {
        super.init(chart: chart, animator: animator, viewPortHandler: viewPortHandler)

        _chart = chart
    }
}
```

It always says

`Overriding method with selector 'initWithChart:animator:viewPortHandler:' has incompatible type '(MyCombinedChartView, ChartAnimator, ChartViewPortHandler) -> MyCombinedChartRenderer'`

I am not sure what's wrong with it. I see other code can do such init by feeding a more specialized sub class.

The CombinedChartView is like:

```
public class CombinedChartView: BarLineChartViewBase
{
...
}

public class MyCombinedChartView: CombinedChartView
{
    // do some customization and override
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change some variable names, conflicting and remove that override keyword with init;

```
public class CombinedChartRenderer: ChartDataRendererBase {

    private weak var _chart: CombinedChartView!

    public init(chart: CombinedChartView, animator: ChartAnimator, viewPortHandler: ChartViewPortHandler)
    {
        super.init(animator: animator, viewPortHandler: viewPortHandler)

        _chart = chart

        createRenderers()
    }
}

public class MyCombinedChartRenderer: CombinedChartRenderer {
    private weak var _myChart: MyCombinedChartView!
    public init(myChart: MyCombinedChartView, animator: ChartAnimator, viewPortHandler: ChartViewPortHandler)
    {
        super.init(chart: myChart, animator: animator, viewPortHandler: viewPortHandler)

        _myChart = myChart // This can be removed by marking baseclass instance '_chart' as public; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change private weak var _chart to _myChart since the sub class is using chart.

Comment: @Wingzero issue is instance of same name can not be used by child class here. you can remove that _myChart instance from your child class and mark your baseclass instance '_chart' as public and use the same instance in child class like (_chart as! MyCombinedChartView)

Comment: I will take a look first